# instance profile association stuck in associating state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

In an attempt to start using AWS Code Deploy, I needed to associate an IAM role to an existing EC2 instance. I created an IAM role, and created an instance profile. I have then attempted to associate the profile to my EC2 instance, and it appears successful, but the association is 'stuck' in the associating state. Any ideas why it won't move to 'associated'? JSON output below:

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI>aws ec2 describe-iam-instance-profile-associations
{
    "IamInstanceProfileAssociations": [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-02199e1931fb3dddd",
            "State": "associating",
            "AssociationId": "iip-assoc-006362cb66d2ab992",
            "IamInstanceProfile": {
                "Id": "AIPAJLOHMQEIG4HMCA5C4",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::712510509017:instance-profile/StoreAppsCodeDeploy"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you created the instance profile and IAM role via CLI. So, could you please check if you have added the role to the instance profile? You can verify this by:

```
aws iam get-instance-profile --instance-profile-name StoreAppsCodeDeploy
```

OR

```
aws iam list-instance-profiles-for-role --role-name YOUR_ROLE_NAME
```

If the instance profile is not assoicated with the role, please run following to compelete that:

```
aws iam add-role-to-instance-profile --role-name YOUR_ROLE_NAME --instance-profile-name StoreAppsCodeDeploy
```

Then run this to diassociate the instance-profile and then run the assoicate-iam-instance-profile.

```
aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id iip-assoc-006362cb66d2ab992
aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id i-02199e1931fb3dddd --iam-instance-profile Name=StoreAppsCodeDeploy
```

Comment: HI Sudo, thanks for your response. You are correct that I did create the profile via CLI (I'm trying to learn how to use CLI). I can verify the role is added:                "RoleId": "AROAJ7XABIUHUC66H2EZ6",
                "CreateDate": "2017-08-29T02:40:31Z",
                "RoleName": "storeAppsCodeDeploy",
                "Path": "/",
                "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::712510509017:role/storeAppsCodeDeploy"

Comment: I tried running your final command, but perhaps the syntax is not right? Unknown options: ec2, associate-iam-instance-profile, --instance-id, i-02199e1931fb3dddd, --iam-instance-profile, Name=StoreAppsCodeDeploy, aws    I'll take a look

Comment: 1> aws ec2 disassociate-iam-instance-profile --association-id iip-assoc-006362cb66d2ab992 
2> aws ec2 associate-iam-instance-profile --instance-id i-02199e1931fb3dddd --iam-instance-profile Name=StoreAppsCodeDeploy
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-iam-instance-profile.html. Sorry, it came as a single line due to formatting.

Comment: Never mind, I ran the two commands separately and they worked, however when I check associations again, the profile is still in a state of 'associating' it doesn't move to 'associated'. ?

Comment: @JamesMatson That's strange and thanks for trying. Are you sure that the IAM Role storeAppsCodeDeploy trusts the EC2 service in it's trust policy? It should be:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Hi Sudo, I thought along the same lines as you, so to remove that as an issue, I added EC2FullAccess to the role using the console. I was going to output the permissions this role has, but am not sure of the syntax. I tried aws iam list-role-policies --role-name storeappscodedeploy but it lists no policy names.

Comment: Actually, tried a different comment "get role" and there is only one policy listed, for code deploy itself?   "Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"

Comment: @JamesMatson So, the IAM Role's trust policy is the issue. As of now the role is only being trusted by CodeDeploy Service. To use the role with EC2, please edit the role's trust policy to include both: "Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com", "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"]. The EC2FullAccess policy is the permission policy i.e. what the role can perform.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_manage_modify.html